# Logic operators in LaTeX? (XOR?)

Tags: symbols

When I google this, it seems that `\XOR` is how you would get an XOR symbol in LaTeX, however that is giving me the 'undefined control sequence' error.  How does one get the xor symbol?

Comment: You probably need to load some package. However, `symbols` does not list `\xor`, so I can’t help you without knowing what the symbol looks like. Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Shouldn't you accept A T's answer instead of TH.'s? Since `\oplus` is clearly superior to `\mathbin{\oplus}` or `\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

How about `\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}`?

Comment: I think the `\mathbin` isn't strictly necessary because `\oplus` is already a binary operator.

Comment: Alternatively, `\lxor` to match `\lor`, `\land`, etc.

Answer (score 121):

`\oplus` worked for me :)

I found this in [List of logic symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) :P

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 15):

What you're looking for is `\veebar` in `amssymb`.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}

$\veebar$
```

If you like, you can create a new command `\lxor`, named to match `\lor` and `\land`:

```
\providecommand{\lxor}{\veebar}
```

Comment: Hey, just added some code tags for you :)

Comment: For reference, the veebar symbol is ⊻, though in LaTeX it might not have a space between the ∨ and the bar

Answer (score 5):

Another way of representing the XOR connective is by using a W-like symbol (as in p W q), also used in Set Theory to refer to disjunctive union. Since this symbol does not seem to appear in the Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list, you can create it by joining two "or" connectives together through the following command:

```
\newcommand{\xor}{%
  \mathbin{%
    {\vee}\mspace{-2.9mu}\nonscript\mspace{0.3mu}{\vee}%
  }%
}
```

that however doesn't work on second levels subscripts/superscripts

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xor}{%
  \mathbin{%
    {\vee}\mspace{-2.9mu}\nonscript\mspace{0.3mu}{\vee}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$A\xor B_{x \xor y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete example. What defines `\mspace`? It is not a default LaTeX command.

Comment: Thanks! It would still be better to give a complete example even though other answers to this question don't. Also, I'm pretty sure this can't possibly be a good way to do it, but I've up-voting anyway as I appreciate the effort ;). (It can't be right to add space like that in maths mode and shouldn't this be declared as a maths symbol?)

Comment: You're right about the example, the spaces and the symbol declaration. The command still needs some fine-tuning. Thanks for the feedback and advice!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of turning your good idea into working code; `\DeclareMathOperator` was not the correct tool and `\ooalign` did nothing; using `\mspace` and `mu` units allows for making it work also in sub/superscripts (alas, not in second level ones).

Answer (score 4):

I found a bit lame solution, but it works for me. Just do:

```
\underline{\vee}
```

Comment: what about `\veebar` from the mathabx package?

Answer (score 1):

I use this one `\overline{\vee}`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to believe this one was overlooked.  In Overleaf, I type the following:

```
P \dot{\lor} Q
```

results in:

P ̇∨ Q

Comment: Actually to provide some spacing consistent with embedded functions, such as P v Q, one can include an inelegant pair of hspaces:

Comment: $ P \hspace{0.01in} \dot{\lor} \hspace{0.05in} Q $

Comment: People are just not using the same notation as you. // You should [edit] the answer to add more information; also you can add image to answers.

Comment: The proper way is `\mathbin{\dot\lor}`.

Comment: No one above suggested \dot\lor from what I saw above.  Either way will work.  Yours is more compact or "proper".  Note my acknowledgement of "inelegant".