What is the Latex code for the logical connective for XOR?
What is the Latex code for exclusive disjunction?  I tried \lxor but it didn't work.

\oplus? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/logic-operators-in-latex-xor

Welcome! I guess you haven't found https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/ yet.

Yes you all answered my question.  Thank you.
